# Windows Azure Namespacemanager issue

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-queues

i trying to create the service bus topic, for which i am using the namespacemanager. the name space manager is not showing the function CreateFromConnectionString.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;

namespace MyWebRole
 {
   public partial class ServiceBus : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        string ConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("");
        var namespacemanager = NamespaceManager. //(here only Equal or Referance Equal option I am getting)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `new NamespaceManager()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are reporting an intellisense issue where the editor is not showing you the options then try the following:
1) Build the project
2) Fix any build/reference errors

The following code should compile with the latest Service Bus Client library: http://www.nuget.org/packages/windowsazure.servicebus

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have updated the serviceBus :). but how to update the service bus DLL. the above mentioned way will update the service bus on the project only i guess.

Comment: That is the recommended approach since you may deploy the app to Azure or have different versions of the ServiceBus client library working with different apps on the same box.